# Batch file copy & paste

Tags: batch-file

I'm using a batch file to copy my Facebook username and password.
It automatically copies my username and it waits 10 seconds, then it copies my Password.

My question is:

Is it possible to create a batch file that copies my username and waits until I paste it, and after I paste it in Facebook it automatically copies my password?

Here is my batch file:

```
@echo off
cls
start "" "https://www.facebook.com/"
echo|set /p="username@hotmail.com"|clip
timeout /t 10
echo|set /p=Password|clip
exit
```

Thank you.

Comment: 1. I don't think there is a way in pure batch to detect whether something is pasted into a username field in a browser; 2. it is not a good idea to store a password as clear text in a batch file; 3. your `set /p` syntax does not look correct to me (although it might work, I can't test it right now);

Comment: Very bad idea ! don't ever store your password as clear text

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible or secure. However you might be able to type automatically with a vbscript, perhaps you should post a second question being open to all script types. Still not secure though and I would not recommend it.